# Doing date range in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM financials
```

How would I limit the query to dates in the past 30 days? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM financials WHERE date BETWEEN now - 30 days AND now
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM financials WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```